# Creating a mathematical formula to price a taxi booking

Tags: calculus, algorithms, mathematical-modeling

I've been asked to create a mathematical formula that will be used to price taxi bookings at a local taxi company.

**Current system used:**

- A table is used as a reference

[image]

**Variables:**

- x is the total number of miles
- y is every stop made

**Conditions:**

- Add £3 for the first 2 miles
- Add £1 for every extra mile incurred (after two miles)
- Add 50p extra for every half a mile incurred (after two miles)
- Add 50p for every stop made (excluding pickup and drop off
- Round to .50 or .00 once calculated

**What I've come up with so far based on the variables and conditions above:**

$$
 f(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
  3 + 0.50y     & \text{$x \leq 2$}\\
  x + 1 + 0.50y & \text{$x  >   2$}\\
 \end{cases}
$$

**How I need your help:**

- Is this formula suitable?
- Can it be improved to factor in an expression that will round the price end result to .50 or .00?
- Can both parts be combined to get rid of the conditional (or perhaps streamlined further if this is not possible)?

Comment: If you add a pound for extra mile, why the prize changes from $2.2$ to $2.3?$

Comment: @mfl because $0.3$ pounds for $0.3$ miles, rounded up to multiples of $0.50$ pounds give this result.

Comment: Note that from $2.7$ to $3.2$ you have half a mile of difference and the prize is the same.

Comment: @mfl The taxi office provided me with this chart, its a bit inconsistent in some parts, so I was trying to standardise it

Comment: @mfl I've just spoken to the owner, he says it is 50p for every half mile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To round a number $z$ to the nearest multiple of $a$, you can use $\lfloor \frac za+\frac12\rfloor \cdot a$. Hence you can use

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}3+0.50y&\text{if $x\le 2$}\\
.50\cdot \bigl(\lfloor 2x+\frac12\rfloor +y+2\bigr)&\text{if $x>2$}\end{cases} $$

Comment: Great thanks! If it's 50p for every half mile, does it change anything?

Answer (score 2):

If it is $50p$ for every half mile then the formula is (included max to avoid the use of "if")

$$f(x,y)=3+\frac{\lfloor\max\{2x-4,0\}\rfloor}{2}\cdot 0.50+0.50\cdot y.$$

Note that this answer is adapted to the change included in your comment and doesn't fit with the original table of prizes.

Comment: IMHO, `max` is no different than `if` (both are conditional).